# Is it possible to backup the TeamViewer product key?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, teamviewer, product-key

I'm in the process of re-installing Windows 10 on my laptop. TeamViewer was pre-installed when I bought the computer, can I backup the product key? If so, where is it located? I've searched the registry as well as several other locations, and have used product key sniffers. I also can't find any info on this specific topic on the web. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There multiple tools you can use [here](https://www.lifewire.com/g00/free-product-key-finder-programs-2625119?i10c.referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F)

Comment: If it was pre-installed it's unlikely that it's a version that requires a key.

Comment: Thank you for your information @D.A, I will look into it.

Comment: Do you think simply copying the binaries, then re-installing them will work @Seth? I only question this because of the, hefty, pricing of the software.

Comment: What? [Teamviewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/) is free for the average non commercial use case. If you actually do have a business license or similar just login in the teamviewer site and download your license again. As you can see in the [FAQ](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-to-activate-Business-license/ta-p/4326) you would also need to do a few things to actually activate it for a device. And/or [just login](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/How-do-I-receive-the-license-key-the-software-and-the-invoice/ta-p/4721).

Comment: I thought it was paid software this whole time. I haven't had much experience with it. Thank you for your help anyways.

Comment: I flagged the post to be closed.